# jQuery Menu how to contain submenus within Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, menu

I am trying to create an 'application' contained in a div on a web page. This can't be any larger than certain dimensions (lets say: 550px by 280px). I have a menu with at least 1-3 sub menus for each item. The problem is, while I know the submenu is no larger than 280px high, the submenus often extend beyond the parent div's bounds (except for the last one which always grows upward not down).

Is there any way to make the menus grow up or down depending on whether it will extend beyond the div's bounds?

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3FqcG/

Notice how the "Salzburg" submenu grows down beyond the bounds of the black DIV? I want that to grow up if it is too long and down if there is enough room.

Currently, I am just using the basic initialization: `$( "#menu" ).menu();`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this in CSS.

This leaves us with javascript. The basic idea is to:

1. calculate the baseline of the menu
2. if this lies outside the boundary

   1. move the menu upwards to correct the position
3. live almost happily ever after

But, we have one major issue:

Though we capture the focus of an element, we don't know when its submenu is displayed & positioned. So although your problem is technically solved, it is by far not a desirable solution.

**UPDATE**

The best **workaround** I could come up with was to:

1. Turn off the animation (to avoid ugly glitches)
2. Add a watcher that would constantly monitor the element that is about to be opened
3. If opened, apply the position correction

Anyway, if you consider coming this far, you might as well override the default positioning of the jquery ui component, with the note that you will not be able to easily update the library. *Update: or try [Rudy Garcia's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16154506/209427) if it works*

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3FqcG/13/)

Code of the demo:

```
var BASE_OFFSET = $('#menuContainer').offset().top;
var MAX_OFFSET = $('#menuContainer').height(); // get the offset of the container
var whenVisible = function($el, callback){ //executes callback when $el is visible
    if($el.is(':visible')){ // if visible
        callback(); // execute callback
    }else{ // otherwise
        setTimeout(function(){whenVisible($el, callback);},10); // do the same check in 10 ms
    }
};
var fixPosition = function($menu){ // correct the position of the menu in respect to #menuContainer
    var h = $menu.outerHeight(true); // take the height of the menu
    var menuBottom = $menu.offset().top + h - BASE_OFFSET; // the baseline of the menu (taking into consideration the BASE_OFFSET)
    if(menuBottom > MAX_OFFSET){ // if this is outside the MAX height
        var diff = MAX_OFFSET - menuBottom; // calculate the difference
        var newTop = $menu.position().top + diff; // modify current positioning with the calculated diff value
        $menu.css('top', newTop + 'px'); // apply it to top (which is also used by jquery to position submenus
    }
    $.fx.off = false; // switch animations back on
};
$( "#menu" ).menu().on('menufocus', function(ev, ui){ // on the event menufocus
    var $ui = $(ui.item); //take the focused element
    var $menu = $ui.children('ul'); // take its related submenu
    if($menu.length === 0){ // if there is none 
        return; // just terminate
    }
    $.fx.off = true; // switch off jQuery effects (otherwise you'll have glitches)
    whenVisible($menu, function(){fixPosition($menu);}); // execute fixPosition when $menu is visible
});
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much for all the time and energy you spent on a solution! Looks like it works perfectly. I selected your answer because it is the clearest explanation, works very well, and has a demo + code to explain. I appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at the API for this widget:

http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/

You can use the position option to position the elements how you want.

This will change the position so that they are within the box, however you will want to dynamically access the last to give it the position you want as the code below will change all menu items to move up 50.

```
$( "#menu" ).menu({ position: { my: "left top", at: "right+5 top-50" } });
```

A complete list of positioning options are also found here: http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Apparently jquery UI has accounted for this and has given the option "within" to make sure your element stays within another element of your choice.

Therefore Your solution should be this:

```
$( "#menu" ).menu({ position: {within: '#menuContainer' } });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This also does work and is built in to jQuery. It is a completely working solution as well! Thank you! :)

Comment: No problem glad to be of help, it is typically best to use their built in solutions so as to not have to hack anything. I would recommend exploring the options provided before deciding to use any library or plugin.